# Identify a Faust quote about being careful when calling upon bad spirits

Tags: quote-source, german-language, johann-wolfgang-von-goethe, faust

As a comment on a disaster, someone quoted orally in German from Faust. They explained the quote as: one should be careful with calling upon bad spirits. The German verb "mahnen" was used.

Where and how is this expressed in Faust?

Comment: Was the verb "mahnen" used in the Faust quote or in a comment on the Faust quote?

Comment: It was in the Faust-quote.

Comment: I have checked the German text of *Urfaust*, *Faust I* and *Faust II* and I could not find any instance of mahn[en] that had anything to do with spirits.

Comment: @Tsundoku By what method?

Comment: Simply by searching digital versions of the texts.

Answer (score 2):

It must be the following from "[Der Zauberlehrling](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Der_Zauberlehrling_(1798))" ("The Sorceror's Apprentice", 1797):

> Ach, da kommt der Meister!
> Herr, die Not ist groß!
> Die ich rief, die Geister
> werd ich nun nicht los.

> Ah, he's coming! see,
> ⁠⁠⁠⁠Great is my dismay!
> ⁠⁠⁠Spirits raised by me
> ⁠⁠⁠⁠Vainly would I lay!
>
> <sub>Translated by [Edgar Alfred Bowring](https://archive.org/details/poemsofgoethe00goet/page/132/mode/2up).</sub>

The word "mahnen" was not in it, but the idea is very clear and corresponds with the one which was brought up in the conversation I related in the question or sub-question.

German Wikipedia takes you to "Der Zauberlehrling", and translations are available.

Part of the idea is that the apprentice of the necromancer is defeated by the spirit he summoned.